# Console window not showing

Tags: c#, nunit

I have this in one of my NUnit tests. I'm using R# to step through my test.  The console window is not popping up to show me the contents for that foreach loop...not sure what I'm missing but yes, there is data for it to loop through so it's not like there's no data here

```
foreach (PostEntry post in posts)
{
    Console.WriteLine("id: " + post.Id);
    Console.WriteLine("title: " + post.Title);
    Console.WriteLine("body: " + post.Body);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: What is your project type. Right click the project in VS->Solution Explorer and click properties. Switch to Build (I think) -> Output Type.

Comment: it's just a class library project..running unit tests there.

Comment: Then your console.write won't go anywhere. Either you need to swicth to a console app or do what @wizzardz suggests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you are working on a class library and you just wanted to see the contents for each loop, can you use  `System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write` rather than Console.WriteLine. The out put will be visible to you in the **Output window**.

```
foreach (PostEntry post in posts)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("loop starts");
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("id: " + post.Id);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("title: " + post.Title);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("body: " + post.Body);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("loop ends");
    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  How can I queue the records up and show a final list for each iteration in in the output rather than see only one iteration in the output window?

Comment: because unless I add a debug break on one of the writeline lines, it won't show the output in the output window.  I don't want to have to put in a break point to only see one.  I want to run this unit test, have the foreach finish and still be able to see the results in the output window for all the records that the foreach processed.  Apparently I'm only able to see one iteration ONLY if I add a debug point on one of the lines in the foreach loop, then look at the output window

Comment: @CoffeeAddict : in order to view the values you have to halt the execution, it can be done either through a break point or using Debugger.Break() function. I have updated my answer.

Comment: right but I want to queue up the writeline and show the list at the end in the output window, is that possible?

Comment: @CoffeeAddict : is it writing any other information in between the loops?